# Convert Array of Dates into Integers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, type-conversion

I am using the C programming language. I currently have a two dimensional character array of dates in this format *"2010-05-01"*. I would like to convert each number into the integer data type and then store them in an integer array. The reason for this is because I need to have an single dimensional array of integers that I can then pass to a function by reference using pointers.

Please see my current code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float values[] = { //Contains 100 float literals }
    int i, j, size = sizeof(values)/sizeof(*values);
    char strings[][10] = {"2010-05-01", "2010-10-01" //Contains a total of 100 dates}
    int dates[size * 3];

    for (i = 0, j = 0; j < size; ++i, ++j) {
        dates[i] = atoi(strtok(strings[j], "-"));
        dates[++i] = atoi(strtok(NULL, "-"));
        dates[++i] = atoi(strtok(NULL, "-"));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d\n", dates[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

This code currently returns a bus error and I do not see why. I am a relative beginner, so sorry if I have done something silly. Any comments would be appreciated and thank you for your time.

Comment: You most propably are passing `NULL` to `atoi()`. I'd recommend to play around with `strtok()` using some even more simple examples.

Comment: as you increment i inside the loop, you should change your condition to something like size-2

Comment: you should provide a working code with let's say 2 literals/dates instead of 100 missing. it's also better for you to debug it with a short example than a full one.

Comment: @daouzli Sorry, that i was supposed to be a j. Due to this, I have edited my question. Yeah, that makes sense, I'll have a play around with some simpler versions and post any updates. Thanks for your help

Comment: for a quick and simple conversion from a string date to a numeric date (seconds since epoch) you can use strtotime()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract independently the year, the day and the month and putting them in a same array, you can put together the years, followed by the months and then the days (supposing that a date is formated as `yyyy-mm-dd`). Such an array could store the following sequence:

```
y1, y2, y3, m1, m2, m3, d1, d2, d3
```

The following code do that kind of thing in the array `ymd`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 2

int main()
{
    int i;
    char strings[SIZE][11] = {"2010-05-01", "2010-10-01" };
    int ymd[SIZE*3];

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        ymd[i*3] = atoi(strtok(strings[i], "-"));
        ymd[i*3+1] = atoi(strtok(NULL, "-"));
        ymd[i*3+2] = atoi(strtok(NULL, "-"));
    }

    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        printf("%d/%d/%d\n", ymd[i*3], ymd[i*3+1], ymd[i*3+2]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output will be:

```
2010/5/1
2010/10/1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. I don't know what I was doing wrong, so I guess the problem was that I was over complicating it too much, for example, by using one array and not doing the simple thing and separating them out. Great answer, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

`char strings[][10]` should be `char strings[][11]` to take the trailing null character into account.

You seem to be parsing each date into three entries into the `dates` array -- is that the intention?

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot about the NULL characters, I'll take a look into that, thanks. What am I doing? I am meaning to put the year of each date into one index, then the month and finally the day. Am I adding the whole date each time?

Comment: No, if you want to place each date into three entries into the `dates` array as year, month and day, your code should work with the `strings` array declared as `[11]`